Determine whether a matrix is non singular
The model of a spacecraft is the following:
\begin{equation*}
\dot{\sigma} = \mathbf{G}(\sigma)\omega 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\mathbf{G}(\sigma) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1-||\sigma||^2}{2}\mathbf{I}_3+\sigma^{\times}+\sigma\sigma^T\bigg) 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{J}\dot{\omega} = -\omega^{\times}\mathbf{J}\omega
\end{equation*}
where $\sigma,\omega \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are, respectively, the attitude and the angular velocity, $\mathbf{J}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} $ is the inertia matrix. Moreover, for a vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, it is used the notation:
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{v}^{\times}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -v_3 & v_2\\
        v_3 & 0 & -v_1\\
        -v_2 & v_1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Considering the following objects:
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{M}(\sigma)=\mathbf{G}^{-\top}(\sigma)\mathbf{J}\mathbf{G}^{-1}(\sigma)
\end{equation*}
Is there a way to establish conditions under which $\mathbf{M}(\sigma)$ is non-singular?

Is there a typo in $\mathbf{J}\dot{\omega} = -\omega^{\times}\mathbf{J}\omega$? You seem to have a $3\times 1$ vector on the left and a $3\times 3$ matrix on the right (unless you mean $\mathbf{J}$ is a tensor?) (Perhaps this is fairly irrelevant - am I right in thinking $\mathbf{J}$ is always invertible and you're mainly interested in $\mathbf{G}$?)

Yes, the inertia matrix $\mathbf{J}$ is always invertible.

The easiest (if not the most elegant) approach seems to be just calculating $\det \mathbf{G}$. It's messy but doable. You can work it out in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials in the $\sigma_i^2$.
